# failed to find target with hash string android-23

Tags: android, gradle, android-build

When trying to build OpenStreetMapView from git://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid, I get this error:

```
failed to find target with hash string android-23: D:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android
```

How can I fix this? Previous questions similar to this suggest checking that android 23 is not installed, but in my case, it is.

Below is some pertinent info:

ANDROID_HOME is `D:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`

`D:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\` contains the directory \android-23\, (as well as android-19, android-21, android-22, android-MNC)

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.osmdroid.example"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 16
        versionName "4.4-SNAPSHOT"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'android.support:compatibility-v4:23+'
    compile project(':osmdroid-android')
    //compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-third-party:4.4-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

I tried changing targetSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion to 22. This causes the error message to change to "android-22" instead of "android-23".

SDK Manager:
[image]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In my case, clearing caché didn't work.

On SDK Manager, be sure to check the box on **"show package descriptions"**; then you should also select the **"Google APIs"** for the version you are willing to install.

Install it and then you should be ok

Comment: This worked.  Had to download the build tools after the SDK manager finished, but definitely didn't need to do the delete .gradle folder or the invalidate cache.

Comment: Thank you! Worked fine.

Answer (score 21):

In Android Studio `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart` solved the issue for me.

Comment: It just improvement to @AlLelopath 's Answer.

Answer (score 17):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33506613/failure-to-find-androidandroidjar6-0-r1#answer-33512421).

Gradle gets stupid from time to time and wiping out the cache is the only solution that I've found. You'll find a hidden .gradle folder under your user home folder and another one wherever the checkout location is for osmdroid.

Comment: I erased the folders, restarded and it is still having the problem

Comment: This error happens for me on a fresh install, so there's no cache to clear.

Answer (score 12):

I fixed the issue for me by opening the Android SDK Manager and installing the build tools for all 23.x.x versions.

See the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: That did it! (using Deco on mac) Thanks!

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any entry called "SDK Manager" in the Android Studio Tools menu anymore...

Answer (score 6):

**Update: Does not apply to the Android Studio released after this answer (April 2016)**

> **Note:** I think this might be a bug in Android Studio.

[image]

1. Go to Project Structure
2. Select App Module
3. Under the first tab "Properties" change the Compile SDK Version to API XX from Google API xx (e.g. API 23 instead of Google API 23)
4. Press OK
5. Wait for the completion of on going process, in my case I did not get an error at this point.

Now revert Compiled Sdk Version back to Google API xx.

If this not work, then:

6. With Google API (Google API xx instead of API xx), lower the build tool version (e.g. Google API 23 and build tool version 23.0.1)
7. Press Ok and wait for completion of on going process
8. Revert back your build tool version to what it was before you changed
9. Press Ok
10. Wait for the completion of process.
11. Done!

Comment: There is no tab for the app module, much less one called "Properties".

Answer (score 3):

Following these reccomended directions seemed to work:

Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: /path/to/android/tools/android

You will require:
1. "SDK Platform" for android-23
2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 solutions to this issue:

1) Download the relevant Android SDK via Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager -> SDK Tools (ensure you have 'Show Package Details') checked. Your case would be Android 6.0 (Marshmallow / API level 21)

2) Alternatively, open your `build.gradle` file and update the following attributes :

- `compileSdkVersion`
- `buildToolsVersion`
- `targetSdkVersion`

either to the most recent version of the Android API that you have installed / another installed version you'd like to use (although I'd always recommend going with the latest version for the usual reasons: bug fixes etc.)

If you're following step 2 it's also important that you remember to update the Android support library version if your app is using it. This can be found in the `dependencies` section of your build file and looks something like this:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'`

(replace `27.0.2` with the most recent support library version for the API level you intend to use with your app)

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue with another number, this worked for me:

1. Click the error message at top "Gradle project sync failed" where the text says ´Open message view´
2. In the "Message Gradle Sync" window on the bottom left corner, click the provided solution "Install missing ... "
3. Repeat 1 and 2 if necessary

23:08   Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string 'android-26' in: C:\Users\vik\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Android SDK providing a solution in the bottom left corner
[image: Android SDK providing a solution in the bottom left corner]

Comment: Please add more information in the case where your image link disappears, so that others may follow the answer even once the link dies.

Answer (score 3):

For me the problem was in that I wrote compileSdkVersion '23' instead of 23. The quotes were the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me by changing `compileSdkVersion` to 24 and `targetSdkVersion` to 24 and change `compile` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.0`

Answer (score 2):

This poblem is solved for me after `Run as administrator` the `Andorid Studio`

Answer (score 1):

Open the Android SDK Manager and Update with latest.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me. I changed SDK path to new SDK location and reinstalled SDK.Its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Android > SDK Manager.

[image]

Comment: I'm not usually a fan of the terse answer, but this is beautifully done. Solved everything for me.

Comment: Thanks, @LeMotJuiced.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when using windows. It turned out that the SDK location in my profiles was the issue. So I had to relocate my SDK folder to documents and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Mine was complaining about 26.  I looked in my folders and found a folder for 27, but not 26.  So I modified my build.gradle file, replacing 26 with 27.  compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion, and implementation (changed those numbers to v:7:27.02).  That changed my error message.  Then I added buildToolsVersion "27.0.3" to the android bracket section right under compileSdkVersion.

Now the make project button works with 0 messages.

Next up, how to actually select a module in my configuration so I can run this.

Answer (score 1):

Download the specific Android release from the link specified in the build console.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused because the code you are running was created in an older API level, And your present SDK Manager doesn't support running them.
So do try the following;
1.Install the SDK Manager that support API level 23.
  Go to >SDK Manager, >Android SDK , then select API 23 and install.
2.second alternative is to update your build.grade app module to change 
compileSdkVersion,compile,and other numbers to your currently supported API level.

Note:please ensure to check the API and Revision numbers and change them exactly. otherwise Your project won't synchronize

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the IDE recognizes that you have the package. It didn't on mine even after downloading 28, so I uninstalled then reinstalled it after realizing it wasn't showing up under File-Project Structure-Modules-App as a choice for SDK.

On top of that, you may want to change your build path to match.

Slightly related, the latest updates seem able to compile when I forced an update all the way to 28 for CompileSDK, and not just up to the new API 26 min requirement from Google Play. This is related to dependencies though, and might not affect yours

Answer (score 0):

AndroidSDK > SDK platforms > and install API Level 23

Comment: can you please explain your answer further?

Comment: what I mean open android studio at the top right hand side click on android SDK Manager and it will show availalable API levels there , look for API level 23 select and click apply