# Failure to find android:android:jar:6.0_r1

Tags: android, maven, gis, osmdroid

I'm trying to build [OSMdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid) with this command:
`>mvn clean install`

The build fails and gives this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project osmdroid-android: 
Could not resolve dependencies for project org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:aar:4.4-SNAPSHOT: 
Failure to find android:android:jar:6.0_r1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 
was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

We are behind a firewall and the network people here have assured me that everything at `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/` is being allowed.

So perhaps what it is looking for is really not there. I'm not sure what `android:android:jar:6.0_r1` is. If I browse to https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/, I don't see a directory named `android`

Any ideas?

Windows 7

Tried deleting contents of `C:\Users\myusername\.m2\repository`, but this had no effect.

The root of the problem seems to be that it is failing to download certain jars from the maven repository:

```
[WARNING] The POM for android.support:compatibility-v4:jar:23.1.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.android.maps:maps:jar:23_r1 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.android.gms:google-play-services:jar:27.0.0 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for android:android:jar:6.0_r1 is missing, no dependency information available
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To directly answer your question, update the SDK, then run the Maven SDK deployer and it should build. Or just import it using Gradle + Android Studio

You probably want to go right to the source.
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-build-OsmDroid-from-source

- Install the Android SDK and update it Set a system environment
  variable for ANDROID_HOME, pointing to your Android SDK install
  location. Windows (My Computer, properties, advanced, environment
  variables...), Linux `export ANDROID_HOME=(path to android sdk install)`
- Install Maven. http://maven.apache.org/download.html (you
  need at least version 3.2.1). You'll also want to add Maven to the
  system path. Windows `set PATH=$PATH%;(path to maven/bin)`. Linux
  `export PATH=$PATH:(path to maven/bin)`
- Checkout the osmdroid source from git to a local folder. (`git clone
  https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid.git`)
- Download Maven Android SDK dependency using Maven Android SDK Deployer. Follow instructions to deploy android sdk package to local repository. (Suggest `mvn install -fn`)
- From the OsmDroid check out location, run the following `mvn clean install`. You will need a device or emulator running.

Gradle has cache issues from time to time and wiping out the cache is the only solution that I've found. You'll find a hidden .gradle folder under your user home folder and another one whereever the checkout location is for osmdroid.

Comment: i just pushed a change which should help (when google updates and deletes old versions of libraries). give it another try

Comment: Yay! Whatever you did fixed it.[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] Total time: 01:48 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-05T09:16:13-07:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 71M/198M

Comment: I'm still having [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33417537/edit) building OSMDroid in Android Studio. Can you help there?

Comment: just import osmdroid in android studio. should just work. don't import the pom, use the gradle bits. Sometimes gradle is silly. delete the ~/.gradle folder and your check out folder /.gradle folder and try it again

Comment: I'm not sure what you are suggesting to do. Strictly speaking, there are no ".gradle" folders, but there are "gradle" folders, `/osmdroid/` and underneath that in `/OpenStreetMapViewer/` and `/OSMMapTilePackager/`. Assuming these are the folders you speak of, I delete them  and then do *File > New > Import Project* and I still get the "failed to find target" error. Also, I'm not clear on what you mean by "delete ... and your check out folder / .gradle folder".

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what how to *not* import the pom. I don't see it in the Android Studio project after the import, but I am doing nothing explicitly to import it or not import it. Sorry for all this hassle.

Comment: Gradle gets stupid from time to time and wiping out the cache is the only solution that I've found. You'll find a hidden .gradle folder under your user home folder and another one whereever the checkout location is for osmdroid.

Comment: That worked! If you would go over to the question and put that as the answer, I'd appreciated it.

Answer (score -1):

Properties -> java build path -> jre -> Execution environment -> Environments button click -> Add External JARs button click -> your .jar path of jdk -> finish

Comment: I think you mean Properties of an Eclipse project. I am not using Eclipse to build, I am doing it from the command line.