# Error for SDK tools Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I've started to learn to make Android apps recently but I've faced a problem in launching Android Studio!

I downloaded android studio and also downloaded SDK  tools from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/) ( I downloaded them separately ) and when I give SDK path to the Studio, it installs SDK successfully but when the project opens, it says that some Android SDK tools are missing!

> Error :Gradle sync failed: Failed to find target with hash string
>   'android-26' in: E:\android-sdk

I'm confused because I can find no problem in my downloading and installing but there is an error!

What should I do?

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417537/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-23

Comment: Click on `Tools -> SDK manager` and verify that the `Api 26` is installed in your computer and also verify that you have installed all the supporting tools .

Comment: I checked it but there were no SDK manager in that file!

Answer (score 0):

install android studio and sdk also( not separately) then create a new project and build them, and if it work then, you can move your sdk file and then connect the path your sdk.
i think you tried separately and some how any data are being missing .

Comment: if I download Studio from google link  , will it contain SDK too?

Comment: @alilolo No you will not get SDK downloaded by default. You can go to Settings-System Settings-Android SDK and download the SDK's you want

Comment: But there  is no download button there . It only asks a path for SDK !!