# after install react-native-device-info error android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

[image]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\AndroidApps\SenFinApp\node_modules\react-native-device-info\andro
  id\build.gradle' line: 29
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-device-info'.

  > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react
  >   -native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.
  >   DefaultDependencyHandler.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
  option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.084 secs

D:\AndroidApps\SenFinApp\android>

I tried to get deviceId using react-native-device-info in react native.then I got below error.
use React-native version
"react-native": "0.48.3",

in line 29

implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'

I follow the instructions of below link:

https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info

please help me

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the actual error? Also, try to refrain from posting messages in image format. Better to copy and paste the output and put it in a quote.

Comment: ok,
Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react -native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies. DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: What version of gradle are you running?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

Comment: This is probably happening since react-native-device-info upgraded to gradle 3+, which required changing `compile` to `implementation`. You'll need to upgrade as well.

Comment: After upgrade got below error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-device-info'.
> Failed to find target with hash string '23' in: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\An
droid\sdk

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33417537/failed-to-find-target-with-hash-string-android-23) could help

Comment: yes ,I went through your path finally its work thanks @Kraylog

Answer (score 0):

Just now I got this issue I fixed using the below fix. "react-native-device-info": "^2.3.2",

1. go to file /node_modules/react-native-device-info/android/build.gradle Replace
2. implementation with compile

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]